# Missing type arguments for generic type 'MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>' (Flutter)

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm getting this error with [`flutter_windows_v1.9.0-dev`](https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/releases/dev/windows/flutter_windows_v1.9.0-dev.zip) but I don't how to solve it.

> Missing type arguments for generic type "MaterialPageRoute< dynamic > ".

Here is my line code

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext c)=>UserProfile()));
```

It underlines `MaterialPageRoute` and `push`. But It worked before I update Flutter to the last version.

Comment: replace MaterialPageRoute with `MaterialPageRoute<void>`

Comment: Simple like HTML for beginners. Thanks a lot. It works

Comment: @SergioBernal Solution worked for me as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

@SergioBernal had the correct answer.  I'm posting it here for visibility since I almost missed his comment above:

replace `MaterialPageRoute with MaterialPageRoute<void>`

as in:

```
 Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
      );
```

Also, This works for PageRouteBuilder as well as in this example:

```
Navigator.push(
        context,
        PageRouteBuilder<void>(pageBuilder: () => SchedulingPage5()),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add void in front of MaterialPageRoute

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (BuildContext c)=>UserProfile()));
```